# How to add a value to specific rows and columns on pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

So here's the deal, I have this dataframe, lets kindly name it lovely_df:

```
   foo? fah? boo? Nice Numbers
0  foo  fah  boo  10
1  meh  fah  boo  20
2  meh  fah  boo  30
3  foo  fah  boo  40
4  meh  fah  boo  50
```

tried to do it like that:

```
lovely_df.loc[lovely_df['foo?'] == 'meh',:]['Nice Numbers'].add(1)
```

And it returns me this:

```
   Nice Numbers
1  21
2  31
4  51
```

Which would be ok if it was saved into lovely_df, but it didn't, so i tried:

```
lovely_df.loc[lovely_df['foo?'] == 'meh',:]['Nice Numbers'] = lovely_df.loc[lovely_df['foo?'] == 'meh',:]['Nice Numbers'].add(1)
```

It actually works but it gives me:

```
<input>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

So this is it, i just wanted to add a specific number to a single column of a few rows without Python crying on me.

Thanks guys!

Comment: That was just a warning, you can just ignore it.

Comment: dont just ignore it, it could bite u later in ur operations. i think you should wrap ur rows and columns within the loc index : ```df.loc[df['foo?']=="meh","Nice Numbers"] = df.loc[df['foo?']=="meh","Nice Numbers"].add(1)```. This [page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) should explain more about chain indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.where` with your condition

```
lovely_df['new_col'] = np.where(lovely_df['foo?'] == 'meh',
                                lovely_df['Nice Numbers'].add(1),
                                lovely_df['Nice Numbers'])
print(lovely_df)

  foo? fah? boo?  Nice Numbers  new_col
0  foo  fah  boo            10       10
1  meh  fah  boo            20       21
2  meh  fah  boo            30       31
3  foo  fah  boo            40       40
4  meh  fah  boo            50       51
```

Comment: Its perfect! Thank you kind Stranger!